# how can i interchage the values in SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, status, invoice, aot

I build a query in AOT where there are many data sets joined to get some data.

For Example: i have following table.

```
Vendor ID  -  Trans Date  -  Invoice Amount  -  Invoice ID  -     Status    -  NTN No.
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     82,000      -    US-102   -      Reg      -  123456
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     10,000      -    US-101   -      NTN#     -  NTN12341
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     82,000      -    US-102   -     UnReg     -  123456
```

What i want to ask is that how can i merge STATUS and NTN nO.
requirement is i want to show the status whether it is Reg aur UnReg I dont want to show NTN# in status. and in front of status i want to display NTN numbers. Like this

```
Vendor ID  -  TransDate  -  InvoiceAmount  -  InvoiceID  -     Status    -  NTN No.
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     82,000      -    US-102   -      Reg      -  NTN12341
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     10,000      -    US-101   -               -  NTN12342
A001       -   1/1/2000  -     82,000      -    US-102   -     UnReg     -  NTN12343
```

Answer (score 0):

in your "Status" textbox do:

```
=iif(Fields!Status.Value = "NTN#", "", Fields!Status.Value)
```

That will blank out the field when the value is NTN, and otherwise just leave them alone.

In your NTN No. field, do:

```
=iif(InStr(Fields!NTNNo.Value, "NTN") = true, Fields!NTNNo.Value, ("NTN"+Fields!NTNNo.Value))
```

That uses InStr() to check if the NTNNo field contains the string "NTN". If it does, then it just uses the existing value.  Otherwise, it appends "NTN" to the front of the string, and uses that.

*Typed up on a phone, watch for syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

Voucher Sales tax code  Source  Name    Status  NTN     Invoice No  Invoice date    Invoice amount  Sales tax rate  Sales tax amount    Total amount
VIV14-0000049   Extra Tax   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        123456      INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   2%  220.00  12936
VIV14-0000049   GST Goods   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        123456      INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   17% 1,870.00    14586
VIV14-0000049   WHT Sales   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        123456      INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   -20%    -374.00 12342
VIV14-0000049   Extra Tax   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        NTN987644       INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   2%  220.00  12936
VIV14-0000049   GST Goods   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        NTN987644       INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   17% 1,870.00    14586
VIV14-0000049   WHT Sales   Purchase order  Pakistan Poultry        NTN987644       INV/001/01  03/13/2014  12716   -20%    -374.00 12342

```
                                            79,728.00
```

here is the actual problem.

Voucher Sales tax code  VEND ID Name    Status  NTN     Invoice No  Invoice date    Invoice amount  Sales tax rate  Sales tax amount    Total amount
VIV14-0000049   Extra Tax       Pakistan Poultry    Reg NTN987644       INV/001/01  03/13/2014   12,716     2%  220.00   12,936 
VIV14-0000049   GST Goods       Pakistan Poultry    Reg NTN987645       INV/001/01  03/13/2014   12,716     17% 1,870.00     14,586 
VIV14-0000049   WHT Sales       Pakistan Poultry    Reg NTN987646       INV/001/01  03/13/2014   12,716     -20%    -374.00  12,342

just because of the duplication there occure problem in total ammount. and i want my report to be like this. in front of REG or UNREG status i want to show NTN number.